# How to summon a slime as a marker

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering how I can summon a slime in a block that is like a marker.
The command I use is:

```
/summon slime ~ ~-1 ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"oC.Slime"}',Glowing:1,--Marker:1--,NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,Size:1}
```

But I can't use marker and those slimes constantly suffocate and drop slimes
also a way if they die they don't drop loot?

Comment: Why is it important that the marker is a slime as opposed to an armor stand or area effect cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Marker` can only be used with armor stands.

To prevent your slimes from suffocating you can use the `Invulnerable` tag instead, it would look like this after adding it to your command:

```
/summon slime ~ ~-1 ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"oC.Slime"}',Glowing:1,NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,Size:1,Invulnerable:1}
```

This is as close as you can get to using the `Marker` tag on slimes. They will still have a hitbox, but they cannot be killed, unless you are in creative mode. They won't have any AI, or gravity.

If you want to prevent an entity from dropping loot, then you can use the `DeathLootTable` tag. It doesn't seem like smaller slimes get that tag from their parents, but you could use it on a slime with `Size:0`:

```
/summon slime ~ ~-1 ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"oC.Slime"}',Glowing:1,NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,Size:0,Invulnerable:1,DeathLootTable:"minecraft:none"}
```

Comment: works ty is there also a way they wont drop slimes on kill?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to kill them under normal circumstances anymore, so that shouldn't be a problem. How and why do you kill them? If you use `/kill`, then you may want to use `/tp ~ -100 ~`, or something like that instead.

Comment: yeah ikr I was just wondering if there wasn't a thing like HandDropChances:[0f,0f]

Comment: The slimes are neither a weapon, nor armor, so that won't work. It may be possible to change the loot tables, but I don't think it can stop smaller slimes from spawning. You could set the size to `0` instead of `1`, those slimes would then only drop slime balls and no smaller slimes.

Comment: I mean the only thing I dont want is them to drop slimes (item)

Answer (score 1):

`Marker`is not a tag that slimes can have. It's a tag for armour stands, which are much easier to handle. The classic marker armour stand is summoned like this:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Marker:1}
```

Comment: Why do you set `NoGravity` to 1? Does that make any difference when `Marker` is set to 1, too? What about the `NoAI` tag? It appears to be completely ignored and doesn't even show up in the data of the summoned armor stand.

Comment: true im just used to it, tho I was wanting the slime cause they have the same look as a block

Comment: `NoGravity` makes them not fall. `NoAI` makes them not get washed by water and stuff like that. I'm not sure anymore whether `NoGravity` is included in `NoAI` or not, that switches back and forth every few versions. If these tags don't show up in the summoned entity, you're doing something wrong.